# Tile layout question closed, but I think it shouldn't have been

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/284367/tile-layout-two-non-adjoined-rooms-off-a-hall-should-tile-be-the-parallel-or) question, which was subsequently closed for being off topic as I guess the moderator saw it as decorating advice. I would argue that my question falls under "Questions you would typically ask a home contractor", as I'm looking for best/common practice in the industry, and is related to tile installation. I wouldn't have a designer in to tackle this if I weren't DIYing, I would ask my contractor what they would do on the majority of their projects. Is there a way I can rephrase and resubmit to get the info I need without running into another closure?

Comment: The question wasn't closed by a moderator, three separate community members came to the conclusion that it's off-topic as written: https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: Given that the questions asked are "from a design standpoint", "would it look weird", and "would it look correct", I believe your question is about decorating and design advice, and don't see how you'd change the underlying question with a rephrasing.

Answer (score 5):

It is/was clearly not a question about tiling practice (where there are some things having to do with layout that are, such as avoiding tiny slivers of tile on one wall, etc.) but about design appearance of two rooms if tiled in accord with˙ common tiling practice, because they could be seen at the same time.

That makes it a design question, whether or not you'd hire a designer. It's appearance and decorating, opinions about "looking weird" and not a functional difference in the tiling.

As such, I, not a moderator, was 1/3 of the close votes. As noted above by a moderator, neither of the other two close votes were moderators. Three community members with sufficient rep (presumed to mean they know what's on topic and not) who all vote to close are sufficient to close a question. That's community moderation in action, and while it sometimes gets out of hand (and can then be corrected by community members voting to re-open - usually after a question has been edited to be on topic) in this case it appears to be exactly correct and the core question is simply not going to be on-topic, no matter how you dance around it.